# When to change my own comment to an answer

Tags: discussion

If a user asks a question, and I come up with a somewhat off the wall suggestion that I'm not sure will work, and the OP responds and says that it fixed the issue, should I convert that comment to an answer, even if I don't explicitly know *why* it resolved the issue? I've read the different Meta questions about commenting versus answering and I felt that because I couldn't be certain it would resolve the issue that it should be a comment. Should I research possible reasons why it resolved the issue and then answer?

**EDIT:** An example can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14665532/delete-rows-from-both-datagridview-and-database/14667731#14667731), this doesn't fit the scenario *exactly* because the OP hasn't yet responded and said if any of the suggestions have been successful, but the answers so far have been nothing more than suggestions of things to *try* and there is no guarantee that any of the answers will be the resolution. On this post I chose to place my suggestion as a comment while some have posted suggestions as answers. Is it really correct to place these as answers or should they be comments that are then migrated to answers if found to be a correct resolution to the issue? I realize at this point this is pushing dangerously close to being a duplicate of some of the comment versus answer questions but I don't feel any of the answers I've read on those questions adequately address the issue of when it's also appropriate to take a comment and make it an answer.

Comment: Could you post a specific example to illustrate this?

Comment: @Asad I was speaking more in a theoretical sense but I have seen specific instances of this. I'm posting this from mobile but I'll look for some of the specific examples when I'm at my computer again

Answer (score 2):

Not every answer has to be a complete solution. If it is helpful post it as answer. Maybe someone else can improve it and add more details – not possible on comments for non-mods – or other people will find it per search.

And if it really is not an answer it can be turned into a comment by a mod any time. The other way is not possible.

Comment: I guess this could also spark a debate about what actually constitutes a good answer, which there are already questions on, but I guess I just feel that a good answer shouldn't be based _purely_ on speculation. So in your opinion when it adequately resolves the issue and has the potential to be helpful to other users, it should be added as an answer?

Comment: You really shouldn't rely on mods to do the thinking for you. I do agree that you should post any helpful information as an answer, particularly if no other answers exist that both diagnose and resolve the problem. You (or a future visitor) can then edit in additional information on *why* the answer works, when (if) new information comes to light. @LeonNewswanger

Comment: @Asad I guess in a sense that was part of my question. When do we deem information as helpful? The answer may be helpful to the OP, but shouldn't it be written in a way that could helpful to everyone? I guess depending on the situation that could also fall under being too localized, which brings me back to my original question of when and how one should decide that their comment would make a good answer.

Comment: After doing some thinking I tend to agree with Asad. I don't think we should be relying on mods to correct something _reactively_ when we could easily be _proactive_ about it. That's exactly why I brought this question to Meta in the first place, so I can be a beneficial user following community agreed upon best practices rather than just saying "if this isn't where this belongs a mod will correct it"